# Converting a field to another type and updating the entire collection in Bulk?

Tags: mongodb, bulk

Here, in my collection, I have "numerical" and "date" field save as string, but I want both of them to be Integer how I can do that. Here is my collection

```
{
   "name": "Thyame",
   "salary": "25000",
   "dob": "1988-01-25"
}
```

and the expected output is

```
{
   "name": "Thyame",
   "salary": 25000,
   "dob": ISODate("1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may perform MongoDB aggregation to change data type and override your entire collection with `$out` operator.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$name",
      salary: {
        $toInt: "$salary"
      },
      dob: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$dob",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  }
//,{$out:"collection"}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/am6nhCqXZgl)

**Note:** If you uncomment `$out`, it will override all records with aggregation result.

Comment: It works but I expect `Salary:25000`  but it shows `NumberLong(25000)` don't we need to `parse` the `integer`?

Comment: @kedarsedai change to `$toInt` (it has limitation to 2,147,483,648). NumberLong is also number, you can add, subtract, divide, etc...

Comment: Okay!! Thank you